# How can I fix this geckodriver error in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I started learning selenium, and when I ran this code...

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   browser = webdriver.Firefox()
   print(type(browser))
```

When I ran that code, I got this error - *Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.*

How can I fix this error? I'm working on Firefox 64bit, and my Selenium Version is '3.141.0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is fixed, I just put the geckodriver.exe into the Python39 folder and it works now perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`gekodriver` is detected in the 3 following ways.

#### 1. Using environment variable `PATH`

Add the absolute path to the `gekodriver` directory into the environmental variable `PATH`.

```
export PATH=PATH:/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/PARENT_DIRECTORY_OF/gekodriver
```

#### 2. Current directory

Keep the `gekodriver` executable in the current directory where the Python script is being executed from.

#### 3. Passed as `executable_path`

For example,

```
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="c:\\gekodriver.exe")
```